# check vs google test framework for c code

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I want to setup a unit testing framework for a c project (c not c++). I have looked into 
[this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C) and checked out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code). I want a framework that I can easily setup for my project that only uses standard c libraries and is compiled and run on fedora 14 (64 bit version). It is not an embedded system like on the stackoverflow question. It looks like check and google test framework would work best. Do you guys know of any advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other or is their a better option out there? I have used JUnit and NUnit in the past for java and c# code. If it matters, I compile and run everything from the command line instead of using one of the IDEs.

Answer (score 3):

> ... that only uses standard c libraries ...

Why is this requirement so important for the test framework if this is not an embedded system? I believe you can keep your production code c, while using any c++ framework.

If the requirement really is C only, I think it's pretty clear that you should go for Check.
If the requirement for C only is not for the test framework then I would go for Google Test, since, from what I have seen, it is offering more.

/Dan

Comment: Yeah, it is 2017, and answer from 2011, but Google Search still keeps **this** in index. So, after 6 years of experience, could you tell, why GTest is better than Check? What advantages are there?