# Is there any test framework for assembly?

Tags: assembly, tdd

guys, I want to know is there any test framework for assembly?

I searched, but seems no relevant topic.

or, I should write my own test case in own code?
just like:

http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1093688

thanks!

Comment: Which assembler language? Which operating system and version?

Comment: @John, heh, I highly doubt it no matter what operating system and processor set

Comment: Wow, a gaping hole in the software world, I bet there is no assembly-language web framework either! I can see it now: `.macro activerecord` ... :-)

Comment: @Jone, @Earlz, yes, the system version and processor set are unrelated to this problem. I just use Intel Assembly for example.

Comment: @dwelch, test some register, because I don't know whether I write the correct code, so I write some test case first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [C unit test libraries/frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code), since calling public symbols written directly in assembly is possible. Writing unit tests in assembly, to keep the same language, could be a cumbersome task, and in the end you're interested more about the output/behavior of the tested function.