# Which C unit test framework?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc

I have just began a new C project, using gcc (currently 4.5.2). Now, before it grows too big, I want to start unit testing it. After some googling I've realized that there are numerous of frameworks to choose from. I cannot afford testing them all.

Note that I don't mind using g++ for the unit tests, as long as I can use gcc for the project itself. It won't hurt if it has good VIM integration, though not mandatory.

So, simply, which should I choose and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Testing C Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've played with libcheck, which is pretty good.  It's been a while since I last used it, but it does the job, and is just straight C.

Answer (score 4):

I'm personally a fan of the [Google C++ Testing Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).  It does require g++ (I don't think there's a way around it), but it handles test fixtures very well and has very useful test output.  This is the framework used by Chrome.  You also don't have to worry about installing it on your system, since it can be built alongside the rest of your source.

A test file can be as simple as this:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "random.h" 

TEST( TestGetRandomInt, ReturnsARandomNumber ){
    ASSERT_EQ( 4, getRandomInt() );
}
```

Comment: Can you use it for testing a project compiled with gcc, although the tests are written for g++?

Comment: @Johan - I believe so. The framework's web page advertises compatibility with gcc, but I've never used it that way.  They do include a Makefile, so you have complete control over how tests are compiled and linked.

Comment: Hehe, I thought the example was crazy, but now I see the charm. :)

Comment: Tried this gtest, but unfortunately I cannot get it to work with object files created by gcc. Seems like I have to compile my project using g++. I guess this framework might be great for C++, but not for my case unfortunately.

Comment: Just spotted a link to someone who's been successful with this. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148576/how-to-test-c-code/1409587#1409587