# How to unit test C (with the help of code blocks)?

Tags: c, unit-testing, codeblocks

I have a task of unit testing C project for homework.
It's written in Code Blocks.
Here's one example from the code:

```
void ServerUserWrite(int Command)  //Command "1" prints an extra row into server. For example addinga new user. it expects that the extra row with the correct data is already existing in the structure.
{
        FILE *UserDataBase;
        int i,j;
        UserDataBase=fopen(UserDatabasePath,"w");
        if(Command==1)
        {ServerUserCount=ServerUserCount+1;}
        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d\n",ServerUserCount);
        if(ServerUserCount>0)
        {
                for(i=0;i<ServerUserCount;i++)
                {
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].UserID);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%s ",UserDB[i].User);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].UserPasswordLength);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].Encrypter);
                        for (j=0;j<UserDB[i].UserPasswordLength;j++)
                        {fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].Pass[j]);}
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].BackgroundColor);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].ForegroundColor);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d ",UserDB[i].UnreadMessages);
                        fprintf(UserDataBase,"%d\n",UserDB[i].UnreadTweets);
                }
        }
        fclose(UserDataBase);
}
```

Well the question is:
Is there any unit testing framework to combine with Code Blocks?
And how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about Code Blocks, but you might wanna use check.h and follow this tutorial :
http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_3.html.
Writing test suites with it is pretty easy. I learnt about it looking at gstreamer-editing-services, may'be will you wanna have a look at their test suite:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-editing-services/tree/tests/check/ges
They reimplemented it but the way it works is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we use Check to unit test our C project too, there is no need to integrate to the IDE, it's more friendly to show the testing result as a plain text.

But there is a framework for C++ unit test which can combined with code block IDE:
[Unit testing for Code Block](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=UnitTesting)

Answer (score 0):

The grand-daddy of all unit-testing in C questions is here:

[Unit Testing C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code)

Again, not specific to Code Blocks, but most of the strategies are standard C.