# Mocking shared library (.so) functions in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, shared-libraries, ctypes

The basic premise is that I want to test functions written in C using the Python unittest framework.

My C code is compiled into shared library files during compilation. I want to be able to mock the `int do_thing(void)` function that is called by `int set_thing(int)`.

```
// helper.c
static int thing = 0;

int get_thing (void) {
    return thing;
}

int do_thing (void) { // do_thing is called by set_thing. This is what I want to mock out
    return thing;
}

int set_thing (int x) {
    thing = x;
    return do_thing()
}
```

In Python, I use ctypes to load the shared object file.

```
# test_helper.py
from ctypes import *
import unittest
from unittest.mock import *


class TestThing(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.lib = CDLL("helper.so") # load library 

    def test_three(self):
        arg = c_int(1)
        with patch.object(self.lib, 'do_thing', Mock(return_value=-2)): # mock self.lib.do_thing() return value as -2
            self.lib.set_thing.argtypes = [c_int]
            ret = self.lib.set_thing(arg) # pass 1 as a c_int to set_thing()
            ret2 = self.lib.do_thing()
            print("ret = {}".format(ret))
            print("ret2 = {}".format(ret2))
            assert ret == ret2
```

The problem with this solution is that my `patch.object` line only mocks `self.lib.do_thing()` and doesn't mock the actual C `int do_thing(void)` function that is loaded through memory of the shared library file.

Is what I'm asking for possible with an already compiled shared library file? How do you mock a function that is already written on disk and loaded in memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock library calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686897/how-to-mock-library-calls)  (Note that Python can’t do this directly, and that this method *does* work within a library if it’s compiled in the normal PIC fashion.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for the reply. While that did work, I need to be able to do this within Python for my problem.

The LD_PRELOAD trick is an interesting thing
[Link](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/low-level/kernel/2016/08/29/16-48-53-the_-ld_preload-_trick/)

Comment: So… would you like an answer that says “This is impossible, but `LD_PRELOAD` is cool.”?  Is that better than marking it as a duplicate?