# How to interpret breakpoints in GDB?

Tags: c, debugging

My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=0;
int j=0;
size_t count=0;
float numbers[20][100];
float velocity[21][101];
char *line = NULL;

FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("vel.txt", "r");

    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

while(i < 20 && getline(&line, &count, myFile)!=-1) {
int len = 0, pos = 0;
    j = 0;
    while(j < 100 && 1 == sscanf(line + pos, "%f%n", &numbers[i][j++], &len))
        pos += len;
    i++;
}
free(line); 
fclose(myFile);

for( i = 0; i < 21; i++ )
    for( j = 0; j < 101; j++ )
    {
       if( i= 1 && j == 1 )
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];  
       }
       else if ( i= 1 && j == 101 )
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];   
       }  
       else if ( i=1 && j >= 2 && j <= 100)
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i][j-1]+numbers[i][j])/2;       
       }   
       else if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j == 1)
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i-1][j]+numbers[i][j])/2;
       }
       else if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j == 101)
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i-1][j]+numbers[i][j])/2;
       }
       else if(i >= 2 && i <= 20 && j >= 2 && j <= 100) //means i goes from 2,20 j goes from 2,100
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i-1][j]+numbers[i][j]+numbers[i][j]+numbers[i][j])/4;
       }     
       else if( i= 21 && j == 1 )
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];  
       }  
       else if ( i=21 && j >= 2 && j <= 100)
       {
       velocity[i][j]=(numbers[i][j-1]+numbers[i][j])/2;       
       }   
       else 
       {
       velocity[i][j]=numbers[i][j];   
       }
    }

return 0;
}
```

I can compile this with gcc but then exe is runnin gforever.So something is wrong.I try to debug like this

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at a1.c:11
11  char *line = NULL;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at a1.c:35
35         if( i= 1 && j == 1 )
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at a1.c:35
35         if( i= 1 && j == 1 )
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at a1.c:35
35         if( i= 1 && j == 1 )
(gdb) n
39         else if ( i= 1 && j == 101 )
```

But I am total beginner,what does this breakpoint tells me?

Comment: `if( i= 1 && j == 1 )` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: A breakpoint "tells" you that the code would executed where the breakpoint is located. A breakpoint is like a forced road checkpoint. The code must stop and report to you, and only continues when you let it.

Comment: Spoiler: `if (i = 1 ..` *assigns* `1` to `i` - but I'd love to know how you can find such a line with gdb...

Comment: All this tells you is that your code reached the breakpoint(s) that you set.

Comment: And you did not find a tutorial how to debug? Hmm... First result for "howto debug gdb": http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

Comment: gcc is a compiler, it does not handle breakpoints. No offence, but you seem to be confused about basic programming fundamentals. You should read a good book or start a tutorial.

Comment: @Olaf - that's my bad, I borked an edit to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Turn on warnings.***

Most C compilers do not have warnings on by default. This is unfortunate because they provide a lot of information for debugging.

Command line compilers usually use `-Wall`, but that often does not turn on all warnings. Yes, this is silly. If you're using `clang` you can use `-Weverything` to get everything. `gcc` has `-Wextra` in addition to `-Wall`. Most have `-pedantic` to ensure you're following the standard.

Fix all the warnings, even if they seem silly. Your code has a bunch that are easily fixed.

***Use valgrind.***

After you've fixed the warnings, you can find memory problems using a program like [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). This is usually as simple as `valgrind ./your_executable`. This will show you all the places you walked out of allocated memory, a very common problem in C.

Interpreting the results can be challenging. [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) has some information about how to do that.

***Break your code up into functions and test them.***

This basic technique applies to any language: write small, testable functions, and test them. By ensuring each small piece works, you only need to worry about the code gluing them together.

In your code, for example, that giant for loop that works with `velocity` and `numbers` should be in its own function. Then it can be tested separately from the code which takes input to build `numbers.

You don't need anything fancy to do the testing, `assert()` works fine to start with. [Here's an example from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675671/unit-test-for-a-c-program/35678528#35678528).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question though.

Comment: @Schwern I have compiled now with gcc a2.c -g -Wextra -pedantic -o a2,compiler is silent,code works

Comment: @RichardRublev You should always compile with `-Wall`. `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` add additional warnings, but they don't replace `-Wall`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It answers the original question *"How to debug my c code which does not execute?"* and the intent of asking about the debugger. Part of asking an expert a question is being gently told you're asking the wrong question. I filled in something they probably didn't know they didn't know about, compiler warnings, because they're off by default and there's no indication they exist. They could fumble around in the debugger, or they can turn on warnings and have their answer in moments.

Comment: This is just a random collection of general debugging techniques, though.  (The first of which probably *does* catch the issue, but the other two are completely non-specific.)

Comment: @RichardRublev You forgot `-Wall`. In gcc `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` do not imply `-Wall`. clang appears to have warnings on by default, one of the reasons I'd recommend developing with clang over gcc.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth This is a specific collection of general debugging techniques which they have demonstrated they're lacking and will allow them to discover the bugs in their code in moments. I could have instead showed them their bug, but that was already done in another answer, and they would have just had another silent problem with their next piece of code. Teach a person to fish and all that. (I did just assume the code has memory problems)

Comment: FWIW, agreed that pointing out their bug would not have been a good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
if( i= 1 && j == 1 )
```

You wind up resetting `i` to `1` each time through the loop.  Change that to

```
if ( i == 1 && j == 1 )
```

One common trick to avoid this is to put the constant expression on the left-hand side:

```
if ( 1 == i && 1 == j )
```

That way, if you forget one of the `=` signs, the compiler will yell at you (a constant expression cannot be the target of an assignment). *Note that I do not personally endorse this practice - I only mention it as one possible option.  IMO, the **right** thing to do is to turn up the warning levels on your compiler*.

**Edit**

Regarding debugging with gdb, all a breakpoint does is stop execution at a particular instruction; it doesn't actually tell you anything.  However, it gives you a chance to examine the state of your program.

To look at the contents of a particular variable, use the `p` command:

```
(gdb) p i
(gdb) p j
```

To examine memory at a specific address, use `x`:

```
(gdb) x/b &i
```

examines a single byte starting that the address of variable `i`:

```
(gdb) x/32b &i
```

examines the 32 bytes starting at the address of the variable `i`.

You can also check the state of your stack using `bt`.  [Here's](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) a handy cheat sheet of gdb commands.

Comment: @John Bode Yes,after these changes,code works just fine.

Comment: All modern compilers will yell at you even without the ass-backwards conditional.

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, but the ass-backwards conditional is guaranteed to halt translation; not necessarily true in the other case.

Comment: @JohnBode: It is the old discussion about readability vs. stability. If you know you use a modern compiler, one should prefer the first nowadays.

Comment: @Olaf: Note that I don't follow the convention myself (it's not a mistake I make that often).  And it doesn't do boo if both operands are variables.  But, I see it often enough in the wild that I thought I should point it out.

Comment: @JohnBode: Not commented on this I would have had stated you Joda conditions obsolete they are with modern compilers. Acceptable they are for such simple conditions, but they really disrupt the reading flow for more complex terms, e.g. with assignments, because you have to "push" the left side before you know the right side. And Humans are not good at using a mental stack.