# How to write unit tests in C

Tags: c, unit-testing

I need to write a *simple unit test* that executes on a given `.c file`. I can't seem to find simple explanations or examples on the web to help me accomplish this. I've seen examples where unit testing frameworks such as `cUnit` are used.. but is this a necessity? Also, I need the unit test to be executable without using any IDE.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code?rq=1 it contains good advice

Comment: thanks, but is using a testing framework essential?

Comment: Just use functions and asserts.

Comment: Do you know of a simple example using functions and asserts?

Comment: Yes, but how would I perform asserts on an input file? i.e. checking if the output in `file x` is equal to some number?

Comment: Thanks for that example. How would I specify which parts of the input file the assert should check? I don't want to hard code the program to look at line x for example as the input file may vary in contents..

Comment: So basically assume that the assert should perform on line 7 of a file? What would be the solution to avoid hard coding this? My aim is to receive files from students where I can then perform unit tests on to check if the correct output(s) are given..

Comment: @jhj For this purpose I'd just compare results from a working program to your students output