# How to run c unit testcases using CMOCKA framework?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, cmocka

I have recently started working on a project written in C language. To add unit test cases, I searched for  C unit test frameworks and I came across this answer [C-unittest-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code). So I chose mocka and installed it from [installation steps](https://github.com/lsjostro/cmocka/blob/master/INSTALL). But I am aware of how to run the written test cases. Can somebody help me to run  from Command line ( GCC command) the simple unit case below:

```
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <setjmp.h>
 #include <cmocka.h> /* A test case that does nothing and succeeds. */ 

 static void null_test_success(void **state) {
    (void) state; /* unused */ 
 } 
 int main(void) {
     const struct CMUnitTest tests[] = {
         cmocka_unit_test(null_test_success),
     };
     return cmocka_run_group_tests(tests, NULL, NULL); 
  }
```

And FYI I am referring [cmocka](https://gitlab.com/cmocka/cmocka). And please let me what are the dependencies required other than GCC and cmocka. Or any Environment variable needs to set for LD paths etc.

Update on this question, i followed following steps:

```
1. git clone https://gitlab.com/cmocka/cmocka.git
2. cd cmocka && mkdir -p build && cd build/
3. cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DUNIT_TESTING=ON ..
4. make && make install
```

After all, steps, if in build dir I execute **ctest tests/**, it is running all the test cases. Now I am stuck on how to follow the same steps for my project and run a dummy unit test case.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after more research on the internet, I came across this very well written article on how to run unit test cases using cmocka. Here is the link [run c unit test cases using cmocka](https://www.samlewis.me/2016/09/embedded-unit-testing-with-cmocka/).

I also forked his git repo & modified it accordingly, have a look at git repo also [git code](https://github.com/samvrlewis/cmocka-embedded-example.git).

Also, I tried another framework gtest, have a look [gtest example code](https://github.com/Dinesh21Kumar/gtest-example.git)

Comment: anybody's guess why the [cmocka site](https://cmocka.org) makes no mention whatsoever of how to actually use it